# Extract values from variables in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array which holds one or more values. If it holds more than one value I am using explode to extract the values.

I have to write a loop, since I do not know the number of values in the array.

Here is my loop:

$m_totalProFood is an array with multiple values.

```
$m_totalProFood = Chicken breast, Tofu,

$i=1;
foreach ($m_totalProFood as $m_proFoodName1)
{
    $m_proFoodValues1 = explode(", ", $m_totalProFood);
    echo "test ".$m_proFoodValues1;
    $i++;
}
```

If I extract individual values then it come correctly

```
$m_proFoodValues1 = explode(", ", $m_totalProFood);
echo $m_proFoodValues1[1];
```

I know I am doing something wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please give some example contents of $m_totalProFood? I can't imagine what you want to do

Comment: `explode` explodes a string, `$m_totalProFood` is array, what did you expect?

Comment: @MichaelFreund the contents of $m_totalProFood = Chicken breast, Tofu,

Comment: explode is a string function, not for an array. count($array) can be used for the number of values in your array

Comment: @baao I want to separate the multiple values from the array into different variables.... I dnt want to count the values in the array...

Comment: What is `$m_totalProFood` - is it array or is it string? Edit your question and add a sample of `$m_totalProFood`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answer

```
 $i=1;
$array = explode(', ', $m_totalProFood);
foreach ($array as $m_proFoodName)
{
echo "test ".rtrim($m_proFoodName,',');
$i++;
}
```

Comment: We already know this is an answer, but please add some explanation about it.

Answer (score 0):

ahhh i see.....

```
$i=1;
$array = explode(', ', $m_totalProFood);
foreach ($array as $m_proFoodName)
{
    echo "test ".$m_proFoodName;
    $i++;
}
```

first make an array out of your string-list, then iterate over it by using foreach

Comment: thanks for the answer... It would correct.... how do i remove the coma from the last value..

Comment: This is the output Tofu
Cod
FitPro Daily,

Comment: explode by "," instead of ", " (without space) and do `echo "test " . trim($m_proFoodName);`